# animation["name"].length works in Editor but not on Android Build

Tags: android, animation, unity-game-engine

here is some code that works when using play mode in the editor with unity remote, but it does not work when running on an actual android build. Just the function with a problem.

```
public IEnumerator Reload(){

    if(isReloading == false){

        Debug.Log ("Reloading");

        if(isShooting == true){

            CeaseFire();

        }

        isReloading = true;

        fpsRigAnimation.CrossFade (reloadAnim);

        guiText.text = "before animation length";

        //problem here
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (fpsRigAnimation[reloadAnim].length);

        guiText.text = "after animation length";

        fpsRigAnimation.CrossFade (poseAnim);

        Debug.Log ("Reloaded");

        isReloading = false;

    }

}
```

The line where I yield for the animation length simply does not run on the android build. I get the "before animation length" in the gui, but not the "after animation length". But both show up when I play it in the editor through the unity remote app. Also the reload animation runs through fine, as well as the debug.log calls in the editor, but the reload animation does not go through at all in the android build.

**Edit**

I just tested the yield statement with a plain float value (2.23f), and it still does not work. So that means the yield statement is the problem too. But the animation clip length is still a problem because when I try making the guitext say the value, it shows nothing on the android, but it does in the editor. I do have other yield statements in the game that all work accordingly.

**Edit: Solution**

It turns out the text file that I was reading in all of the stats from needed to be in a special folder called "Resources" to be included in an actual build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the text file that I was reading in all of the stats from needed to be in a special folder called "Resources" to be included in an actual build.

Answer (score 0):

May revise your logic giving conditions shall work.

**Like**

```
if (animation[“name”].time > animation.["name"].length)
{
     //do something
}
```

Give it a try and tell.